# Finding a generator of an ideal in an algebraic function field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, computer-algebra

I have an algebraic function field $\mathbb{Q}(x,y)$, where $y$ satisfies
$$ (y^2-1)^2 = x^2(1+x^2), $$
and I need to find a rational function that has a first order root at $x=0,y=1$ a first order pole at $x=0,y=-1$, and no other roots or poles.

Is this possible? How do I go about finding such a function or proving that it cannot exist? Is it an issue that $y+1$ has a branch point of order $\frac12$ at $z=\pm i$? I need to automate this process, so is there any standard algorithm for this that I need to look at?

This might be easy (I don't know), but I asked a related question on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/520586/computing-an-integral-basis-of-an-algebraic-function-field-y4-2zy2z2-z4-z) and got no responses at all, so I want to ask here this time.

Comment: Your points are singular points on the curve so talking about order of zeros and poles of functions at these points is not well-defined. Having said that, Magma can do these kind of computations.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch Hmm. How do I modify the question so that it makes sense? I don't have access to Magma. I have a certain differential $f\,dx$ with known poles and their residues, and I need to find $v$ so that $f\,dx = c\,d(\log v)$, hence the question.

Comment: You need to find a non-singular model of the curve.

Comment: Since your function field has positive genus, there is no rational function having only a single root if that root has degree $1$ and order $1$ (because such a function would be an isomorphism between your field and $\mathbf{Q}(z)$).  But there are two places $P,Q$ of the field which contain both $x$ and $y-1$, so you need to be careful when talking about the order of the root at $x=0,y=1$.  In order to have a chance of the function existing, you must mean that it has first order roots at both $P$ and $Q$, and likewise for its poles.  Magma says that no such function exists.